# Copy and paste from Word into CKEditor 4.5.5 incomplete on Mac / Firefox

Tags: ckeditor

Copy and paste from MS Word to CKEditor works fine in all browsers on the PC. But in Firefox on a Mac, headings in bullets disappear and some other style issues are also ripped.

My config is like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;h3;h4';
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'styles', groups : [ 'format', 'insert' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align'] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'link' ] },
        { name: 'about' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode' ] }
    ];
    config.removeButtons = 'Undo,Redo,Image,Flash,Smiley,PageBreak,Iframe,SpecialChar,HorizontalRule,Cut,Copy,Anchor,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Save,Newpage,Preview,Print,Templates,About,Help,Document,Language,Blockquote,Indent,Outdent,CreateDiv,NewPage,Styles,Font,FontSize';
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
    config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow';
    config.autoGrow_minHeight = 250;
    config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 600;
};
```

Any one encountered this issue also?

Answer (score 0):

Please report this issue in our CKEditor bug tracker at http://dev.ckeditor.com. Thanks!